# How to add name value to input element

Tags: angular5, angular-forms

I am looping a data, from the data, I am adding the name value into the input field, but not at all set. what is the issue here?

My form template:

```
<form novalidate name="myForm">
  <div ng-show="myForm[addVas.name].$error.pattern">Error will come </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="addVas.input" [attr.disabled]="addVas.disabled ? '' : null " name="{{addVas.name}}" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]/" (blur)="addAdnlVasAfterInput(addVas)" placeholder="Provide value of shipment"
      class="form-control">{{addVas.name}} <!--getting value here-->
  </div>
</form>
```

I am not getting throw the error, when user input instead of number in to charters. how to solve that?

Now I have update my `name` field in to `[name]="addVas.name"` but I not confirm the name sent, unless if i get error message

Comment: Did you mean setting the value?, use value='{{name}}'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some confusions between Angular versions. ng-show should be *ngIf or [hidden] with reverse logic, ng-pattern is [pattern]. [attr-disabled] can be [disabled], etc.. Pattern /^[0-9]/ doesn't allow more than 1 digit, I am not sure it was your aim. If you use a property as pattern expression, the use [pattern]="property":

Here is what I suggest:

```
     <form #myForm>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="addVas.input" 
             [disabled]="addVas.disabled" [pattern]="addVas.pattern"
             [name]="addVas.name" #input="ngModel">
        <div *ngIf="input.errors && (input.dirty || input.touched)" >
            <div [hidden]="!input.errors.pattern">
                Should be a number
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fhuwlj)

Comment: I am happy with your answer. still this is not works when i use the `ngFor` - loop. how to solve that? first element is behave well not the next one. how to solve this? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cvgcvy

Comment: I am unable to access your demo :(

Answer (score 0):

The properties cannot perform interpolation.
You need to use property binding for setting values to properties.

Try this:

```
[name]="addVas.name"
```

instead of

```
name= "{{addVas.name}}"
```

Comment: I added by your suggesion, but i am see the name in the html using developer tool

Comment: Are you trying to set the value of the input field as addVas.name?

Comment: can you please see my update in the question ,  i am not getting any error on wrong inputs

Comment: Try this ng-show = myForm.addVas.name.$error.pattern

Comment: The error always shows, still I din't see the name in input, can you please update here in the demo : `https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-validation?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html`